# Installing ubuntu alongside windows 8 without partitioning

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows

My disk partitions are as follow:

`c:`6.88/49.1GB

`d:`159/270GB

`e:`239/292GB

`f:`164/319GB

[image]

Windows 8 is running from `c:`

The problem is that windows doesn't allow me to partition my disk further,stating that I have **exceed the maximum number of partitions**.

Could anyone tell me how to go about dual-booting?

And also my windows is 32 bit and linux is going to 64 bit.This isn't gonna pose any problems right?(my hardware is 64 bit capable)

[image]

Comment: just divide your extended partition and install Ubuntu on that.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I've included a pic of the disk management,could you explain a bit more?

Comment: please include the pic of gparted partition editor which was already preinstalled on your Ubuntu live disk. It would be more clearer. If the gparted is not preinstalled then run `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install gparted` command on your terminal. It willl install automatically.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I'll post it as soon as my ubuntu copy has finished downloading.

Comment: @AvinashRaj included it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an extended partition to contain all partitions (except Windows) as logical partitions. An extended partition counts as one primary partition and a logical partition can boot Linux and not Windows.
So the drive should look like:

- Primary - Windows
- Primary - Extended
- - Logical - Ubuntu
- - Logical - Swap
- - Logical - Data 1
- - Logical - Data 2
- - Logical - Data 3

Comment: I've included the pic of my disk management,could you explain it a bit more please?

Comment: @phpcoderx As I can see from the screenshot, you already have an extended partition ('/dev/sda4'). All you have to do is to resize '/dev/sda5' and create two logical partitions with the unallocated space: one for Ubuntu and one for the swap.

Comment: Is swap necessary? how big should swap partition be?

Comment: @phpcoderx It should be about the size of the RAM or the double, but even 128 MB is better than nothing.